# Group rows together by multiple columns with or condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates, dense-rank

I have a table of people that I need to have a way to find duplicate records by multiple possible scenarios.  For instance, group together if fname, lname and address are the same OR if fname, lname, dob are the same, OR if fname, lname, and Email are the same.  I can't figure out a way to do this in SQL.  I am using the above examples solely as examples, because the grouping criteria will eventually be much more strict.  I've set up an example with data in [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb7f2/10).  My desired result would group records 2-5 together and 1 and 6 would be unique rows.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(255),  
    LastName varchar(255),    
    Address1 varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    State varchar(255),
    BDay Varchar(255),
    Email Varchar(255)
);


INSERT INTO Persons
SELECT 'RICK', 'ALLEN', '44 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '1/2/1970','help@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNIFER', 'ALLEN', '123 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '4/8/1980','test@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNIFER', 'ALLEN', '123 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '4/8/1981','test@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNIFER', 'ALLEN', '42 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '4/8/1980','test@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNIFER', 'ALLEN', '123 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '4/8/1980','test2@test.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'STEVEN', 'ALLEN', '555 Street', 'Minneapolis', 'MN', '2/8/1980','help@test.com'
```

Comment: What do you mean group them together? Which DOB and email would you use, or does it matter? Like, what would the expected result be--a comma separated string or just ordering them together? Not my DV, just seeking clarification

Comment: `OR` is valid in SQL, so did you try that?   SQL Fiddle is a nice supplement, but you need to include your sample data, code, and desired results in your question itself, so that it will be useful to future readers after the SQL Fiddle link goes dead.

Comment: Group together means creating a golden record for the group.  I want to create a Master Record with an ID and then assign all the records that were used to create that Master Record to that ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `not exists` clause:

```
select  p1.*
from    Persons p1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Persons p2
        where   p1.id < p2.id and
                p1.FirstName = p2.FirstName and
                p1.LastName = p2.LastName and
                (
                    p1.Address1 = p2.Address1 or
                    p1.BDay = p2.BDay or
                    p1.Email = p2.Email
                )
        )
```

[Working example on SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb7f2/19/0)

Replying to your comment, you can mark duplicates in the table with an update query:

```
with    dupe as
        (
        select  min(p1.ID) as OriginalID
        ,       p2.ID as DupeID
        from    Persons p1
        join    Persons p2
        on      p1.id < p2.id and
                p1.FirstName = p2.FirstName and
                p1.LastName = p2.LastName and
                (
                    p1.Address1 = p2.Address1 or
                    p1.BDay = p2.BDay or
                    p1.Email = p2.Email
                )
        group by
                p2.ID
        )
update  p1
set     DupeOfID = dupe.OriginalID
from    Persons p1
join    dupe
on      dupe.DupeID = p1.ID
```

[Working example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/481aa/1/0)

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution.  This is a method I never even thought of.  One other requirement I have is to create an ID for these "golden records" and assign that ID back to the original records that were grouped together so they associate to the golden record.  I'm not sure this solution allows that?

Comment: You can't do that @CodeMonkey because you have it as an identity property. You could insert a new row and delete the others, or something similar like reseed the column. Nice answer Andomar.

Comment: You could group the rows in a CTE and mark all following rows as duplicates of the earlier row, example added

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer.  This looks to produce the results I'm after.  I'll do some heavy testing on it and will mark as the answer if it validates. Thanks again!

Comment: @Andomar, thanks again! I've modified the code a bit to go another level.  I'm now trying to grab the most common values for each group and return that in the master record.  Is there an easier way to do it than this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d07f2/53

Comment: Looks good, CTE3 might be simpler with `max(case when Match_RankByCount_FName = 1 then FirstName end)` instead of the joins. You could simplify the code to "most common occurrence of value in a group", and ask that as a new question?